# Proving that a field is not a splitting field of any polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to prove that $Q(2^{1/3})$ is not a splitting field of any polynomial $p(x) \in Q[x]$.

I know I need to show that there does not exist any polynomial in $Q[x]$ that has all of its roots in $Q(2^{1/3})$. I know that a basis for $Q(2^{1/3})$ over $Q$ is $\{1, 2^{1/3}, 2^{2/3}\}$.  But I can't figure out how to start. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: What you say you know isn't accurate. What you need to show is that that field is not *the minimal field* that contains all the roots of some polynomial(s) over the rationals. Anyway, do you know that if that field is the splitting field of a family of polynomials, then the extension is *normal*, which means that any **irreducible** polynomial which has a root there completely splits there?

Comment: Actually, a lot of polynomials split in $\Bbb Q[x]$ (e.g., $p(x)=x^2-4$ splits in $\Bbb Q$, ergo in $\Bbb Q[2^{1/3}])$. What you need to show is that *some* polynomial doesn't split in $\Bbb Q[2^{1/3}]$.

Comment: @Joanpemo Very interesting. I actually overlooked the minimal requirement. I do not know the part about the extension being normal. That not been covered in my class yet.

Comment: @Clayton I don't think that is accurate, either. What could probably be you meant is that some polynomial *which has a root in the field* doesn't split in it.

Comment: @Clayton Is there a difference between $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. I have not encountered the former notation (with the square brackets) before in this context. (I am familiar with its use for the polynomial ring $F[x]$.)

Comment: @gues11010111001 Over any field $\;F\;$  and an element $\;w\;$ in some extension, we have that $\;F[w]=F(w)\iff w\;$ is algebraic over $\;F\;$ . Reasonably easy proof which can serve to find out whethen one understands the basic definitions. Thus, in your case, there is no difference.

Comment: @Joanpemo: You're correct! Haha, I knew what I had in mind, but I didn't express it very clearly. Thanks for the correction. There are, of course, a lot of polynomials that don't split in the field :-P

Answer (score 3):

Splitting fields are normal, so if it is a splitting field, any polynomial with a root has all the roots in the field. But $x^3-2$ is such a polynomial, and clearly does not contain all its roots since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a purely real field.

**Edit (since the op doesn't know about normality):** The other option is ad hoc, but works, if it's a splitting field, since it has degree $3$ it has no proper, non-trivial subfields, hence it must be the splitting field for a third-degree polynomial with all real roots. But then it is a totally real field, i.e. it has no embeddings into $\Bbb C$ which do not end in $\Bbb R$. However, since $K\cong \Bbb Q[x]/(x^3-2)$ this is a contradiction since the map which sends $\overline{x}$ in the quotient to $\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a map which does not land in a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the fact that splitting fields are normal? I haven't encountered that concept in my class.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a finite extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}$ for some $\alpha$. The condition 'finite' means that $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,...$ is dependent for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now pick the smallest such $n$, then you can write $\alpha^n = ...$ with '...' some combination of $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...\alpha^{n-1}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now I claim that this gives you the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$!

For your example, with $\alpha=2^{1/3}$, you already know that $\alpha^3$ is dependent on $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$. Yes: $\alpha^3=2*1$. Thus $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3-2$ and this polynomial is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Now to your problem. If $\mathbb{q}(\alpha)$ is the splitting field of some polynomial, then some irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Thus it has its roots in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Thus we can  check the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and see if it their irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}$ generate $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. We only have to check $\alpha$ (Why?): It has minimal polynomial $X^3-2$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Now you have to check that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ does not contain all roots of $X^3-2$. It does contain $\alpha$ so divide $X^3-2$ by $X-\alpha$ and then look at the resulting polynomial $X^2+\alpha X+\alpha^2$. It has roots $b\alpha$ with $b$ some element satisfying $b^2+b+1=0$. Do you know about roots of unity? Otherwise just show that no such element is in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.